# jqgrid SELECT Dropdown pupulating with JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, dropdown

I got a working jqGRID with a dropdown in a cell.

```
{ name : 'oid', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'note', sortable : false, editable : true, edittype: 'select', 
                                                        formatter: 'select', 
                                                        editoptions:{
                                                            dataUrl: "http://api.kurse.dailyware.ch/orte/liste",
                                                            buildSelect: function(response){
                                                                var data = typeof response === "string" ?
                                                                            $.parseJSON(response) : response,
                                                                 s = "<select>";
                                                                $.each(data.data.orte, function () {
                                                                    s += '<option value="' + this.oid + '">' + this.name +
                                                                       '</option>';
                                                                })
                                                                return s + "</select>";
                                                            }
                                                            }
                                                        }
```

It gets populated by this JSON source:

```
{
    "header":
    {
        "timestamp": "2015-09-24 03:47:18"
    },
    "data":
    {
        "func": "listview",
        "orte":
        [
            {
                "oid": "1",
                "name": "Buero Gruetter Stooss",
                "strasse": "Muehledorf 30",
                "plz": "5013",
                "ort": "Niedergoesgen"
            },
            {
                "oid": "3",
                "name": "FBS",
                "strasse": "Das ist wahr",
                "plz": "46",
                "ort": "oke"
            },
            {
                "oid": "2",
                "name": "TCS Sicherheitscenter",
                "strasse": "Industrie 17",
                "plz": "8000",
                "ort": "Zuerich"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "200"
}
```

As soon as I edit a row the dropdown is there with the right values.

Here is my complete GRID

```
$.ajax({
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: "http://api.kurse.dailyware.ch/kurse/liste",
                                success: function(data){
                                    jqgrid_data = data.data.kurse
                                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    console.log('test')
                                    jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                                            data : jqgrid_data,
                                            datatype : "local",
                                            height : '250',
                                            colNames : ['ID', 'Datum', 'Zeit', 'Name', 'Inhalt', 'Preis','Teilnehmer','Kursort'],
                                            colModel : [
                                                    { name : 'kid', index : 'kid', key : true, sortable : false, width : '50px' }, 
                                                    { name : 'kursdatum', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'sdate', editable : true, sorttype:"date",unformat: pickDate, width : '100px' }, 
                                                    { name : 'kurszeit', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'tax', editable : true, width : '80px' }, 
                                                    { name : 'kursname', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'name', editable : true }, 
                                                    { name : 'kursinhalt', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'amount', editable : true }, 
                                                    { name : 'kurskosten', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'note', align : "right", sortable : false, editable : true, width : '80px' },
                                                    { name : 'kursteilnehmer', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'kursteilnehmer', align : "right", editable : true, width : '100px' }, 
                                                    { name : 'oid', editrules: {required: true}, index : 'oid', sortable : false, editable : true, edittype: 'select',                               
                                                        editoptions:{
                                                            dataUrl: "http://api.kurse.dailyware.ch/orte/liste",
                                                            buildSelect: function(response){
                                                                var data = typeof response === "string" ?
                                                                            $.parseJSON(response) : response,
                                                                 s = "<select>";
                                                                $.each(data.data.orte, function () {
                                                                    s += '<option value="' + this.oid + '">' + this.name +
                                                                       '</option>';
                                                                })
                                                                return s + "</select>";
                                                            }
                                                        }            
                                                        }],
                                            rowNum : 10,
                                            rowList : [10, 20, 30],
                                            pager : '#pager_jqgrid',
                                            sortname : 'kursdatum',
                                            toolbarfilter: true,
                                            viewrecords : true,
                                            sortorder : "desc",
                                            gridComplete: function(){
                                                var ids = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                                                for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
                                                    var cl = ids[i];
                                                    be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Edit Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').editRow('"+cl+"');\"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>"; 
                                                    se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('"+cl+"');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
                                                    ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";  
                                                    jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ca});
                                                }   
                                            },
                                            editurl : "http://api.kurse.dailyware.ch/kurse/add",
                                            caption : "Kursübersicht",
                                            multiselect : false,
                                            autowidth : false
                                    });
```

But there are two things not working:

1. The cell is empty ( not displaying anything ) as long as I don't edit the row
2. If I click on edit, the dropdown is displayed but doesn't take the default value corresponding to the cell value.

How do I fix these two things?

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid allows to use `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` properties of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) instead of `value` property. Thus you can good use `dataUrl` which points to existing source providing the described JSON data. You need just write small callback function `buildSelect` which convert the JSON data to HTML fragment

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">Buero Gruetter Stooss</option>
    <option value="3">FBS</option>
    <option value="2">TCS Sicherheitscenter</option>
</select>
```

or to any other which more corresponds to the text which you want display in the dropdown. It's important just to understand that `buildSelect` as the callback function with one parameter `data` which represent the response from the server from `dataUrl`. The callback `buildSelect` should parse the data and returns **string** with represent `<select>` with all required options. It's important that the returned data should be the string, but some more resent version or jqGrid allows to use jQuery wrapper to the same data too.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I managed to populate the dropdown when I edit a row with the function added in the question. But the cell is empty as long as I don't call the edit row function. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @da.eXecutoR: Could you post jqGrid code with test data which you use to fill the grid. It sounds that you use texts instead of ids during *filling* the grid. So the `formatter: "select"` can't display the data. You can use `formatter: 'select'` if you don't have `value`.  There are many ways to solve the problem, but one have to go back to the step of **filling the grid**.

Comment: I did insert my grid construct in the question. I removed the definition "formatter: 'select'" and now I see the "oid" in the rows. As soon as i edit the row, the dropdown appears and also the right value is selected. So I guess there is only a small piece missing, the one to display the corresponding name.

Comment: from the kendoui framework I remember, I had to add a function which made the translation of key = value pair. But it's the first time I'm using the jqgrid so sorry for the stupidness ;-)

Comment: @da.eXecutoR: If you provide the code on the backend (`http://api.kurse.dailyware.ch/kurse/liste`) then you can solve your correct problem in many ways. The first one: working with textes only ind no ids for `'oid'` column. Another way would be extending the response from `http://api.kurse.dailyware.ch/kurse/liste` so that you returns the data [{oid:.. name: }] inside of the `/kurse/liste` response. It allows you don't make separate request to `/orte/liste` and **first fill of `editoptions.value` of `'oid'` column and **then** create the grid.

Comment: @da.eXecutoR: By the way you should fix your jqGrid code in many places.  You have currently no `act` column in `colModel`. You can remove `gridComplete` and add column `{name: "act", formatter: "actions"}` which creates editing buttons internally. If you would use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then you can use `{name: "act", template: "actions"}`. Additionally you should replace `width : '100px'` to `width : 100` and `height : '250'` to `height : 250` or better to `height : 'auto'`. I recommend you to add `gridview: true, autoencode: true` options

Comment: @da.eXecutoR: You should don't use different `index` and `name` properties in `colModel` because it breaks sorting and filtering (by usage of [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching)) local data.